# what may be the issue with my code, unanimously showing this error?

Tags: php

I am new to programming but atleast at intermediate level this type of errors are mind sucking. I have searched so many resources on google, but didn't found any fruitfull solution to this.
Here is my code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$q = "SELECT * FROM songs where 1";
$r = mysqli_query($con, $q);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r))
{
    echo "<a href='download.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>
    '><img src='images/a.jpg' height='80' width='80'></a>" . "<br>
    <br>
    ";      echo $row['name']. "<br>
    ";      echo $row['artist']. "<br>
    ";      echo $row['file']. "<br>
    ";      echo $row['size']. "<br>
    <br>
    <br>
    ";  
}
```

Please help me, THANKING YOU ALL IN ANTICIPATION.

Comment: Is it in a php file..?

Comment: is this code ??

Comment: Do you see that you are echoing <php then echo then ?> all inside of a double quoted echo?  It's no wonder that this isn't displaying as intended.  Keep researching.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct code for you:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    $q = "SELECT * FROM songs where 1";
    $r = mysqli_query($con, $q);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r))
    { ?>
         <a href='download.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>'> <img src='images/a.jpg' height='80' width='80'></a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <?php echo $row['name'];?> <br />
        <?php echo $row['artist'];?> <br />
        <?php echo $row['file'];?> <br />
        <?php echo $row['size'];?> <br />  
        <br><?php
    }
?>
```